# How do I read config sections from web.config only

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am trying to read config sections from web.config file. 
But the below code lists all config sections from web.config file and also machine.config file from .Net Framework folder

```
foreach (ConfigurationSection section in config.Sections)
{
    cboSection.Items.Add(section.SectionInformation.SectionName);
}
```

How do I read config sections from web.config only

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this..

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Comment: I am reading all config sections and listing it in a drop down. I want to show the sections only from web.config file in the root folder. :(